# Output two candidates with the same amount of votes

Tags: c#

sorry for the homework question, I know some don't like them but I'm at a loss.
I've written a code as per my task that has the user entering who they want to vote for etc, which all works. The second part the task is to modify it so if two candidates have the same vote instead of in 3rd is "...." in 2nd is "..." (same amount of votes as who came third) in 1st is "..." it will output in 2nd is "...+..." in 1st is "..."

Here's my code so far;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create empty arrays
        int[] votes = new int[5];
        string[] names = { "Ahmed", "Boo", "Celine", "Didi", "Elaine" };
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, names[i]);
        }

        //input votes
        Input(votes);

        //sort votes
        Sort(votes, names);

        if (votes[0] > 0)//If there are any votes for the top candidate then do not display the output
        {
            //output sorted data
            Console.WriteLine("\nVote summary");
            Output(votes, names);

            Console.WriteLine("\nIn third place: {0}", names[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("In second place: {0}", names[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("And the winner is: {0}", names[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No votes were made!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }//end Main

    static void Input(int[] arr)
    {
        int vote = EnterInt("Enter number of candidate you wish to vote for (0 to 4) or -1 to quit:");

        while (vote != -1)
        {
            if (vote < 0 || vote > 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid vote");
            }
            else
            {
                arr[vote]++;
            }
            vote = EnterInt("Enter number of candidate you wish to vote for (0 to 4) or -1 to quit:");
        }//end while
    }//end InputArray


    public static void Sort(int[] votes, string[] names)
    {
        for (int pass = 1; pass < votes.Length; pass++)
        {
            int smallestPos = FindSmallest(votes, votes.Length - pass);
            if (smallestPos != votes.Length - pass)
            {
                Swap(votes, smallestPos, votes.Length - pass);
                Swap(names, smallestPos, votes.Length - pass);
            }
        }//end for
    }//end Sort

    public static int FindSmallest(int[] votes, int num)
    {
        int smallestPos = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (votes[i] < votes[smallestPos])
            {
                smallestPos = i;
            }
        }//end for
        return smallestPos;
    }//end FindSmallest

    public static void Swap(int[] votes, int first, int second)
    {
        int temp = votes[first];
        votes[first] = votes[second];
        votes[second] = temp;
    }//end Swap

    public static void Swap(string[] names, int first, int second)
    {
        string temp = names[first];
        names[first] = names[second];
        names[second] = temp;
    }//end Swap

    public static void Output(int[] votes, string[] names)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < votes.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", names[i], votes[i]);
        }//end for
    }//end Output


    static int EnterInt(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        int num;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
        {
            Console.Write("Error! Please enter an integer number:");
        }//end while
        return num;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you only care about the top three then just do the comparisons, there are 4 possibilities, the top two are equal, the second and third are equal, all 3 are equal, or none are equal.  It becomes a little more complex if you want to include the 4th and 5th candidates in the case of one or more ties.

Comment: You wouldn't need 2 swaps if you create an object to hold everything (e.g. `class Candidate` with properties `Name` and `Votes`). As for the task there are several approaches, e.g. using sorting. Or you can simply find candidate with maximum number of votes, remember that number, output all candidates with same number (concatenating them with `+`), find next lower maximum of votes, repeat.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding this, but surely you can just add an if to compare [1] and [2], if they are equal then output your 2nd ... + ..., if they are not then use you existing logic?

Comment: Thank you for the input everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you use a **single collection** to store all the candidate names and their vote counts (as suggested by @Sinatr in the comments) since it makes the code much simpler by enabling you to use handy Linq functions such as .OrderBy().

To achieve this you have many options at your disposal, you can either create your own **Candidate Class** with the **Name** and **Votes** properties, or you can use an already predefined type such as a **Tuple(string, int)** or a **Dictionary**, like the one I used in my sample code.

As you have noticed, the hard part of this problem is sorting the vote standings of the three candidates with most votes. The approach I've used is to **group** the candidates by **equal number of votes**, then sort those groups from highest to lowest amount of votes. Afterwards, I proceed to retrieve the names of the candidates while keeping a counter of the maximum amount of names to display in the standings, which is 3.

I tried to make the code as simple as possible while keeping your structure for the most part, please let me know if you have any doubts.

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> candidates; //Make the variable accesible from any method for simplicity
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //initialize dictionary
        candidates = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        candidates.Add("Ahmed", 0);
        candidates.Add("Boo", 0);
        candidates.Add("Celine", 0);
        candidates.Add("Didi", 0);
        candidates.Add("Elaine", 0);

        //Print candidate names
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, GetCandidate(i));
        }

        //input votes
        Input();

        //output votes if highest vote candidate has any
        if (candidates.Max(c => c.Value) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vote summary");
            Output();

            //to arrange the standings we need to group the candidates to evaluate if they share the same amount of votes
            //additionally I choose to skip the group of candidates who have 0 votes, as there is no point on displaying them

            var grouped_candidates = candidates.GroupBy(c => c.Value).Where(g => g.Key > 0).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key);

            //we can only display 3 names in the standings so we set a counter
            int standing_spots = 3;

            string firstplace = string.Empty, secondplace = string.Empty, thirdplace = string.Empty;

            //retrieve winner(s)
            var first_group = grouped_candidates.ElementAt(0);
            var winner_names = first_group.Select(c => c.Key);
            firstplace = GetStandings("In first place: ", standing_spots, winner_names);

            //retrieve second position(s)
            var second_group = grouped_candidates.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
            if (second_group != null)
            {
                var second_names = second_group.Select(c => c.Key);
                secondplace = GetStandings("In second place: ", standing_spots, second_names);
            }
            //retrieve third position(s)
            var third_group = grouped_candidates.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
            if (third_group != null)
            {
                var third_names = grouped_candidates.ElementAtOrDefault(2).Select(c => c.Key);
                thirdplace = GetStandings("In third place: ", standing_spots, third_names);
            }

            //Print standings
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdplace)) { Console.WriteLine(thirdplace); }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondplace)) { Console.WriteLine(secondplace); }
            Console.WriteLine(firstplace);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No votes were made!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static string GetStandings(string standing_txt, int standing_spots, IEnumerable<string> names)
    {
        if (standing_spots > 0)
        {
            if (names.Count() >= standing_spots)
            {
                standing_txt += string.Join("+", names.Take(standing_spots));
                standing_spots = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                standing_txt += string.Join("+", names);
                standing_spots -= names.Count();
            }
        }
        return standing_txt;
    }
    static string GetCandidate(int index)
    {
        return candidates.ElementAt(index).Key;
    }
    static void Input()
    {
        int cand_num;
        do
        {
            cand_num = EnterInt("Enter number of candidate you wish to vote for (0 to 4) or -1 to quit:");

            if (cand_num >= 0 && cand_num <= 4)
            {
                candidates[GetCandidate(cand_num)]++; //increment candidate vote value
            }
            else if (cand_num != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid vote");
            }

        } while (cand_num != -1);
    }
    public static void Output()
    {
        foreach (var candidate in candidates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", candidate.Key, candidate.Value);
        }
    }
    static int EnterInt(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        int num;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
        {
            Console.Write("Error! Please enter an integer number:");
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. sorry for the late reply I've been swamped